# Stop cron daemon "symmetrical.xm" error messages in Terminal mail

Tags: cron

After upgrading to High Sierra (I think) I've started receiving the following message almost every time I start up Terminal:

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/MyUsername
```

I had some [problems](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-could-not-be-installed-on-your-computer-fixed.2058800/#post-25149270) upgrading to High Sierra so I strongly suspect this started after the upgrade, but cannot be absolutely certain.

When I enter the `$ mail` command and read the messages (which can amount to hundreds at one go) this is what is written:

```
Message 1:
From MyUsername@Users-MacBook-Pro.local  Tue Nov 28 21:37:04 2017
X-Original-To: MyUsername
Delivered-To: MyUsername@Users-MacBook-Pro.local
From: MyUsername@Users-MacBook-Pro.local (Cron Daemon)
To: MyUsername@Users-MacBook-Pro.local
Subject: Cron <MyUsername@Users-MacBook-Pro> /Users/MyUsername/Library/symmetrical.xm/symmetrical.xm cr
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=MyUsername>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=MyUsername>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/MyUsername>
Date: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 21:37:01 +0800 (+08)

/bin/sh: /Users/MyUsername/Library/symmetrical.xm/symmetrical.xm: No such file or directory
```

Also, when I run `$ crontab -e`, this is what is returned:

```
37 * * * * /Users/MyUsername/Library/symmetrical.xm/symmetrical.xm cr
~                                                                                                                              
~                                                                                                                             
"/tmp/crontab.SsevmMDt1o" 1L, 72C
```

I am trying to figure out why the Cron Daemon is sending me these error messages. To clarify, I would *not* like to suppress mail from cron altogether; so, I don't want to

- Delete the `MyUsername` file at `/var/mail/`, OR
- Change the MAILTO variable in `/etc/crontab` to `MAILTO=""` (as suggested in [this link](http://www.putorius.net/2015/03/stop-cron-daemon-from-sending-email-for.html))

Instead, I'd be really grateful it if someone could help me understand

- How/why this started happening
- What I can do to stop it from happening again (or if I should stop it from happening at all)
- Which app/script requires the missing file/directory called `symmetrical.xm` and why

Any other additional information to add to the points listed above would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

---

macOS High Sierra v10.13.1 (17B48)

Comment: What is the command in cron supposed to do - what did it output when you ran it from the cimmand line?

Comment: Instead of suppressing mail from cron it might be better to fix the reason cron is sending you mail in the first case: `/Users/MyUsername/Library/symmetrical.xm/symmetrical.xm` seems to be missing

Comment: @Mark Do you mean when I run `$ cron`? I get this: `cron: can't open or create /var/run/cron.pid: Permission denied`

Comment: @patrix Yes – I was wondering if someone could help explain which script requires the file because when I tried Googling "symmetrical.xm" no relevant results were returned. (I'm definitely not trying to suppress all mail from cron, only the ones that are related to this "symmetrical.xm" problem; sorry I didn't make that clearer in my original post.)

Comment: No what happens when you run the command in a shell not via cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- open Terminal
- run `ls -l /Users/MyUsername/Library/symmetrical.xm/symmetrical.xm`
- If you get an error of any kind (directory or file not found) run `crontab -r` to remove your crontab.

Comment: Thank you, this helped - the messages seem to have stopped. Still don't really get what was going on though!

Comment: @sabriele You probably installed some software in the past which created the `symmetrical.xm` library as well as the cron job to regularly run the command. The software seems to be gone, but the cron job remained, trying to execute a non-existing file.